# How to fix that my git outputs to a pager

Tags: git, configuration

Somehow my git outputs to a pager.
How can I get back its normal behavior -- output to tty directly?

More details -- I don't know if it's because I was copying configurations from someone else years ago, but many of my git commands output to a pager. For e.g., if I type `git branch`, my whole xterm window get cleared and a single line of `* master` is showing in `less`. If I type `q` to quit, I see nothing remains in my tty.

That's very annoying to me, but for years I've been put up with it, until now, when I cannot bear any more.

Comment: @JosephSible, yes, it's a duplicate (which is so hard to find the proper kw to search for it). Thanks

Comment: Sound like what you actually want is `LESS=X` so that `less` doesn't clear the screen when it's finished.

Comment: Ah! Thanks @WilliamPursell, that's another annoyance I've been put up with for years but don't know how to search for the answer. You've just saved me from another misery. thx again.

Answer (score 1):

to expand on what xpt wrote:

For one git command on current repo use:

```
git config pager.branch 'less -F -X'
```

For one git command on all repos use:

```
git config --global pager.branch 'less -F -X'
```

If it's just one-off use, it's better to use:

```
git --no-pager branch
```

Comment: Oh, just noticed that you're using `pager.branch`, how about `core.pager`, are they interchangeable? Would you give a link to backup your answer please? Thx.

Comment: It  comes out of `git help git-config` or `git help git`. I ran into it trying to check the current branch via a script.

Answer (score 0):

To save people from more clicking, here is it:

```
git config --global --add core.pager "less -F -X"
```

without disabling the paging for other things.